# Socket reconnect logic

Tags: java, android, sockets, websocket

I'm using the following websocket library for Android:

https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client

I want to be able to reconnect every 5 seconds on disconnect as long as the current activity is  alive. This is my logic.

```
    @Override
    public void onConnected(WebSocket websocket, Map<String, List<String>> headers) throws Exception {
        Log.e(TAG, "connected");
        mIsActivityAlive = true;
        super.onConnected(websocket, headers);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(WebSocket websocket, WebSocketFrame serverCloseFrame, WebSocketFrame clientCloseFrame, boolean closedByServer) throws Exception {
        super.onDisconnected(websocket, serverCloseFrame, clientCloseFrame, closedByServer);
        Log.e(TAG, "disconnected");
        if (mIsActivityAlive) {
            while(!mWs.isOpen()) {
                Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
                Log.e(TAG, "reconnecting");
                connectWs();
            }
        }
    }

public void connectWs() {
    try {
        mWs = new WebSocketFactory().setConnectionTimeout(5 * 1000).createSocket("MY_WS_URL");
        mWs.addListener(wsAdapter);
        mWs.connectAsynchronously();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This logic works fine - however, after the websocket connects after reconnect, it keeps trying to reconnect. I thought having `!mWs.isOpen` in the while loop would solve this issue. I logged `mWs.isOpen` in the `onConnected` callback and it's `true` , however it keeps appearing `false` in the `onDisconnected` callback. I have a feeling it has to do with the `Thread.sleep` but I'm not sure where to start looking.

Comment: @efekctive would I have to change the source of the web socket api? in other words, where should I declare the boolean as atomic ?

Comment: @efektive that's not where the issue lies, it's in `mWs.isOpen()`

Comment: Why do you need the loop? If it tries reconnecting and fails, won't it wind up in `onDisconnected` again? I don't have websocket experience, but it seems natural for reconnecting to have the same callback system as connecting the first time.

Comment: @VinceEmigh good idea, I'll look into that

Comment: If you look at the logic. the onConnected event has not been fired so the socket is not open

Comment: From the javadocs: onConnected "Called after the opening handshake succeeded." If there is no handshake there is not opening.